# pytest not found when running from a conda environment in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, pytest, conda, github-actions

I'm trying to test my package with GitHub Actions, where the package runs in a `conda` environment. It all works fine locally. But on GitHub Actions, it says [`pytest: command not found`](https://github.com/MaxGhenis/microdf/runs/1015197619?check_suite_focus=true) with [this workflow file](https://github.com/MaxGhenis/microdf/actions/runs/219372640/workflow):

```
name: Build and Test [Python 3.6, 3.7]

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Setup Miniconda using Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: goanpeca/setup-miniconda@v1
        with:
          activate-environment: microdf
          environment-file: environment.yml
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          auto-activate-base: false

      - name: Build
        shell: bash -l {0}
        run: |
          pip install -e .
      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          pytest
```

I tried removing `pytest` from the `conda` environment and [instead running](https://github.com/MaxGhenis/microdf/actions/runs/219392895/workflow) `pip install pytest` before running `pytest`, but that gave a different error: `error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the `shell`, as in the `Build` step:

```
- name: Run tests
  shell: bash -l {0}
  run: pytest
```

Comment: Works like a charm but needs to appear also at installing step, that was not the case for me. Thanks!